# Jquery Ajax MVC controller URL issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a jquery code which opens a dialog. This dialog is a partial view which renders from the response of a jquery Ajax call "`http://test.com/ControllerA/ViewDetails`". Ajax call code looks like below

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ViewDetails",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
```

The dialog box has button which has to make another Jquery Ajax call (this has go against a different controller and action). Ajax code looks like below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ControllerB/Search",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
```

The above ajax call fails to find search action because The URL will get changed to `http://test.com/ContollerA/ControllerB/Search`.

I feel this is something related to a route config. But i need some directions from you all.

Comment: add "~/" before the url i.e "~/ControllerB/Search" , it represent the root/url further path , so in your case http://test.com/ControllerB/Search

Comment: If you are externalizing the urls to separate javascript variable assign the urls in hidden fields and then use the value of hidden field in javascript file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("ViewDetails", "ControllerA")", 
    type: "GET", 
    dataType: "html",
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Search", "ControllerB")", 
    type: "GET", 
    dataType: "html",
```

This way you're using the route table and not generating urls willy nilly

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use

```
 url: '../ControllerA/ViewDetails'
```

it worked for me when the culture is in url

Comment: this works in a partial view rendered in a same page. In my case i was opening a dialog box. So i need to use the @Url.Action.